# How to detect back navigation triggered by swiping and stop it on iOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a form in my react native app. When a user tries to fill it and tries to navigate back without saving it. I would like to show an alert to confirm this action. If the user decides to submit this form, the triggered back action must be canceled. On Android, the back button can be controlled with an event listener. But how can we achieve that on iOS using react navigation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native disable swiping StackNavigator in TabNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114810/react-native-disable-swiping-stacknavigator-in-tabnavigator)

Comment: edison, im a bit unclear coz ios doesnt have a back button , so is there an explicit back button which you have made in the app? kindly share details so i can help.

Comment: iOS doesn't have a back button. But users can swipe from left to right in order to trigger go back event. When user makes an attempt to go back in any way, I want to do some checks and take control of the go back event.

Comment: @EdisonD'souza did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible currently. However, you could disable the swipe gesture on the screen instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware about disabling swipe. But that is not a solution in my case.

Comment: Like I said, what you want to do is not possible with React Navigation currently. So you don't have a choice if you want to prevent back navigation.